# Set Ubuntu Desktop Network Proxy Settings programmatically on 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy

I try to create a fully automated desktop setup using preseed et al. The desktops will be running behind a "corporate proxy" (I know, I don't like that either) and therefore need to be configured accordingly.

To get the proxy configured theres a fair amount of documentation such as https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/.

Most of the tasks are easy to automate, but I do not quite understand where the `Network Manager` persists its proxy settings (refering to the first section of the documentation linked above). Any hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dconf-editor or dconf
/system/proxy/

For example:

> dconf read /system/proxy/http/host
>      '192.168.0.1'